# Who to ask questions on prices?

Tags: self-publishing, book, marketing, research, money

I want to get advice for my book and e-book pricing (telling that I am to advertise them with AdWords).

My question: What is such an adviser called? Maybe "marketolog", "counselor", "adviser", etc.? How do I find one on the internet?

And how much does such advice cost?

Answer (score 1):

A professional that prices books is called

– *big drum roll*-

a publisher.

Since, here, it is an e-book, you are the publisher, so do some basic research.

There are many sites that deal with this issue, plus forums, a simple Google search will show sites like:

1. [The shocking secret about ebook prices that will help you price your ebook](https://web.archive.org/web/20151006115514/http://bubblecow.com/the-shocking-secret-about-ebook-prices-that-will-help-you-price-your-ebook);
2. [How to price your ebook](https://web.archive.org/web/20150331235710/https://www.millcitypress.net/how-to-price-your-ebook);
3. [Ten things you may not know about ebook prices](https://techcrunch.com/2014/01/15/ten-things-you-may-not-know-about-ebook-prices/).

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are useful, but also:

**The market.**

When you experiment selling something for a certain price and seeing how well it does (and maybe iterate with 2-3 different price points), that's the best way to tell what price something should be.